# Getting download callback from chrome custom tabs

Tags: java, android, android-webview, chrome-custom-tabs

Is there any alternative for following code in WebView, **for getting download callback** in the case of **Chrome custom tabs for android**

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
        //handle download action internally
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?